# Support for multiple domains/subdomains in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app that has a similar setup to Tumblr, that is, you can have either:
(1) Subdomain hosting (your-username.myapp.com)
(2) Domain hosting (your-username.com)

Both would forward to a personalized website for that user, created with my application.

How can I accomplish this in Rails? I have been able to get (1) working with subdomain-fu, but I'm not sure how to get (2) working. Any pointers (plugins, gems, tutorials), etc. would be greatly helpful, I can't seem to find any.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The principle for domains is the same as the subdomain - find the domain, map to an account.

The details will depend on how your hosting is going to handle the DNS.

I am currently using Heroku and its wildcard service. 
In this case, the domain is mapped with a cname to the subdomain hosted by my Heroku app. From here I can work out the associated account and details.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I've found a much easier way: http://www.arctickiwi.com/blog/7-host-and-domain-based-routing-in-ruby-on-rails

Not exactly an answer but this is the best I can give. Maybe this'll help you too.

Ideally, [this blog post from transfs.com](http://transfs.com/devblog/2009/01/21/hosting-multiple-domains-from-a-single-rails-app/) and subdomain-fu should do the trick. I've been trying to implement it, however, and they don't seem to play nicely together.

Basically, if I don't include the intiializer, the subdomain route works fine. If I include the initializer, the subdomain route breaks (everything gets caught by map.root). I have a feeling it's with the way it builds the condition string in the initializer. If you can figure out how it breaks, then you'll have a working app.

My initializer:

`module ActionController
  module Routing
    class RouteSet
      def extract_request_environment(request)
        env = { :method => request.method }
        env[:domain] = request.domain if request.domain
        env[:host] = request.host if request.host

        env
      end
    end
    class Route
      alias_method :old_recognition_conditions, :recognition_conditions
      def recognition_conditions
        result = old_recognition_conditions
        [:host, :domain].each do |key|
          if conditions[key]
            operator = "==="
            if conditions[key].is_a?(Regexp)
              operator = "=~"
            end
            result << "conditions[:#{key.to_s}] #{operator} env[:#{key.to_s}]"
          end
        end
        result
      end
    end# end class Route
  end
end`

My routes (just for development). You'll see my local development domain, stiltify.dev. Sorry, I tried to make it look good in here but I couldn't get the code block to look nice. I put it on pastie instead: http://pastie.org/940619.

The comments section in [Ryan Bates' screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/123-subdomains) was very helpful, and got me to figure out the subdomain => false and the other errors they were getting into. Still didn't fix the problem though!